# View shell colours in file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file that has a lot of shell/terminal colour codes in.
I was hoping I could get vscode to view the file in the colours and hide the colour codes.
Or at the very least be a bit like the Markdown preview panel.

```
[1m[31mERROR 
[39m[22m
[2m149:30[22m 
[0m [90m 147 | [39m      [90m
[90m 141 | [39m          colour[33m:[39m [33mSomeUtils[39m[33m.[39m[33mSOME_CONST[39m[33m,[39m[0m
```

Trying to read 2000 odd lines with all the colour codes mixed within becomes quite hard to distinguish what is what.

I could pipe it back into the shell terminal, but I would like it to be editable and react to changes as I go.

Comment: can you try just cat the file in to another file?  `cat file.txt > file_without_colors.txt` ... might work.

Comment: There is a _still_ open feature-request for VS Code to support this: [ANSI color support in edit buffer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38834). As of now, there is no built-in or 3rd-party extension support for this :(

Comment: Thank you @GinoMempin I will follow. @DarrenSmith if I wanted it removed, I would have just done `replace/.\[\d+m/''`